# Can the choice of reflection angle for light can be derived from a minimality condition?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

When the light hits on a surface, it reflects with the "same" angle as the one that hits  the surface. I was wondering if this choice of angle can be explained by a minimality condition?

Answer (score 2):

This follows from from [Fermat's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle).  A derivation for the reflection is e.g. found [here](http://www.nd.edu/~jjohns27/11-30%20notes.pdf).